# Expand nested elements of a list within a data.table in R, according to a second list column

Tags: r, data.table, unnest

I have a data.table in R that is

```
> data.table(value="one",list1=list(c(list("one1"),list("one2"),list(c("one3 1","one3 2")))),position=list(c(0,1,2)))
     value     list1  position
  1:   one <list[3]>     0,1,2
```

where the `<list[3]>` element is

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "one1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "one2"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "one3 1" "one3 2"
```

I want to lengthen the data.table so that I have

```
value   list1     position
one     "one1"    0
one     "one2"    1
one     "one3 1"  2
one     "one3 2"  2
```

where "one3 2" corresponds to position 2. So far, all my attempts result in position 3 being listed for "one3 2". Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 dt1[, .(value, list1 = unlist(list1),
   position = c(mapply(\(x, y) rep(x, lengths(y)), position, list1)))]
```

-output

```
    value  list1 position
1:   one   one1        0
2:   one   one2        1
3:   one one3 1        2
4:   one one3 2        2
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realized my `dt1` has `list1` values which are empty lists. This then results in the `Error in rep(x, lengths(y)) : invalid 'times' argument` error. Would you have any ideas how I can account for empty lists which then result in 0 lengths?

Comment: @user321627  do you want to remove those empty cases or return NA

Comment: @user321627 can you show an example.  This example `dt2 <- data.table(value="one",list1=list(c(list("one1"),list(NULL),list(c("one3 1","one3 2")))),position=list(c(0,1,2)))` works though with the code

Comment: @user321627 can you try `yourdat[, c(.(value = value), lapply(seq_along(list1), \(i) {x <- list1[[i]]; l1 <- lengths(x); x[l1==0] <- NA_character_; data.table(list1 = unlist(x), position = rep(position[[i]], lengths(x)))}))]`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option if this is your actual dataset, though not sure about other logic that might apply to your data:

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

dt <- data.table(
  value="one",
  list1=list(c(list("one1"),list("one2"),list(c("one3 1","one3 2")))),
  position=list(c(0,1,2))
  )

dt %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_longer(c(list1, position)) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_longer(list1) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(temp_index = readr::parse_number(list1) - 1) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(position == temp_index) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-temp_index)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   value list1  position
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 one   one1          0
#> 2 one   one2          1
#> 3 one   one3 1        2
#> 4 one   one3 2        2
```

Comment: Unnest can handle multiple columns provided each unnests to equal length, so you can simplify this solution to just two unnest calls.  `dt %>% unnest_longer(c(list1, position)) %>% unnest_longer(list1)`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can use `unnest` twice like below

```
dt %>%
  unnest(c(list1, position)) %>%
  unnest(list1)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  value list1  position
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 one   one1          0
2 one   one2          1
3 one   one3 1        2
4 one   one3 2        2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another funky approach relying only on `data.table`:

```
dt[, .(value, list1 = unlist(list1, recursive = FALSE), position = unlist(position))][, .(list1 = unlist(list1)), by = .(value, position)]
#>    value position  list1
#> 1:   one        0   one1
#> 2:   one        1   one2
#> 3:   one        2 one3 1
#> 4:   one        2 one3 2
```

or a bit simpler:

```
dt[, .(value, list1 = list1[[1]], position = position[[1]])][, .(list1 = unlist(list1)), by = .(value, position)]
#>    value position  list1
#> 1:   one        0   one1
#> 2:   one        1   one2
#> 3:   one        2 one3 1
#> 4:   one        2 one3 2
```